# Implementation of getline in a while loop comparison

Tags: c++

I am currently working on this source code and I was wondering why this logic implementation doesn't work?

Logic that works:

```
std::cout << "Enter a string (q to quit): ";
std::string str; 
getline(std::cin, str);
while(str[0]!= 'q'){
// do stuff
}
```

Logic that doesn't work:

```
std::cout << "Enter a string (q to quit): "; 
std::string str; 
//getline(std::cin, str);
while(getline(std::cin, str) != "q")
```

I have also tried making it compare "q\0" because I know that getline gets rid of the newline character in the input and adds a null character \0 at the end, but that doesn't work either..Is this task impossible? I just want to save a few lines of code space ahaha...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `getline(std::cin, str)` returns a `istream&` , which is not a string literal. For more information on [std::getline](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/).

Comment: Darn.. >.>, I guess it was not possible.

Comment: Actually, I'd fear that the stream's conversion to `void const*` may yield a pointer which can be equality compared to a `char const*` to which the string literal will happily decay.

Comment: Actually, it does return something, either 0 or 1 on success or failure of the getline. I can't believe I forgot that. Which is why it never evaluates to what I want it to..

Comment: @TakShing: No, it does not return 0 or 1. It returns a reference to the stream you passed in. Because of the [bool conversion operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool), (or the `void*` conversion operator pre-c++11), it can be evaluated in a boolean context (such as an if statement), evaluating to `true` if the stream is in a good state, and `false` if it is in an error state (which it would be put in after an unsuccessful read operation).

Answer (score 4):

The `std::getline()` function doesn't return a `std::string`. It returns an `std::istream&` which can be used for chaining more input operations and which needs to be used to determine if the input operations was successful. You want your loop to look something like this:

```
for (std::string str; std::getline(std::cin, str) && str != "q"; ) {
    // do whatever needs to be done
}
```